# how to extract numerator and denominator and root of a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

```
FLOAT_NUM = 2*math.sqrt(3)/5
>>> 0.23094010767585033
```

considering i started with FLOAT_NUM's value how to extract numerator==2 and denominator==5 and the value uder root==3?
for example:

```
input >> 0.23094010767585033
output>> 2,5,3
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an input *and* your desired output? If you're not sure how you'd get the output, even just on paper with a calculator, then this is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: @RandomDavis input: 0.23094010767585033
output: (2,5,3)

Comment: So given a float `f`, you want to find `n`, `d`, and `r` where `f = n* r**0.5 / d`?

Comment: This is mathematically impossible without more information. You have 3 independent variables in this equation.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, exactly

Comment: 4,3,10 are also solutions to your equation

Comment: @shadow Are you saying you just want to find some values that work, or find your original values? Because the latter is, as was already stated, totally impossible.

Comment: If this is solvable, it will have infinite number of `n, d` pairs.

Comment: You don't. `FLOAT_NUM` doesn't store any information about how it was created; it's identical to what you would get from `FLOAT_NUM = 23094010767585033/100000000000000000`.

Comment: @RandomDavis yes some values are okay

Comment: 23094010767585033, 1, 100000000000000000 is the simplest solution

Comment: @zfj3ub94rf576hc4eegm is it possible to find all possibilities ?

Comment: There are infinite possibilities

Comment: @shadow: I believe the number of solutions is infinite.

Comment: @shadow there's practically an infinite amount of possibilities

Comment: With what precision?  Don't forget that floats are imprecise by their nature.

Comment: Also, `2*math.sqrt(3)/5 == 0.6928203230275509`

Comment: @RandomDavis that's sad, is there at least a way to find one simple solution with small values with condition the value under root doesn't equal one ?

Comment: @chepner i can see now it's impossible to achieve :'/

Comment: @shadow it's not impossible to find at least one solution; see the answer below.

Comment: It seems you're really just looking for rational approximations to `FLOAT_NUM**2`. From that perspective, `Fraction.limit_denominator` might help. E.g. using your example value, `Fraction(FLOAT_NUM**2).limit_denominator()` gives me `4/75`, and taking square roots and normalising in the usual way gives `2√3 / 15` (which is what I think you meant to write instead of `2 * sqrt(3) / 5` in the original question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is impossible to find a reverse operation, as the same value can be obtained from multiple ones:

```
def f(a,b,c):
  return a*np.sqrt(b)/c

f(1,1,1) == f(2,1,2)
```

you can definitely find *a set of values* that produces your output (and by changing initial guess x0 you can control "what region of values" it should search for, you can add constraints etc., just look at [documentation of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html))

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(a,b,c):
  return a*np.sqrt(np.abs(b))/c # for safety we remove sign from b

def loss(x, value):
  return (f(*x)-value)**2


print(minimize(loss, x0=(1,1,1), args=( 0.23094010767585033,)))
```

Outputs

```
      fun: 1.407352885154195e-12
 hess_inv: array([[2.19894411, 0.10853698, 0.53500981],
                  [0.10853698, 0.97322067, 0.16951733],
                  [0.53500981, 0.16951733, 0.81315655]])
      jac: array([ 1.15720094e-06,  4.00176469e-07, -3.21558937e-07])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 20
      nit: 4
     njev: 5
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.47495072, 0.68534754, 1.70255982])
```

Thus for a=0.47495072, b=0.68534754, c=1.70255982 you will get almost the value of interest (up to 1e-12 error).

Now things will get a bit more tricky if a, b and c are supposed to be integers. You can still go through the path of optimisation - simply replace scipy with any library for genetic algorithm or other gradient-free optimiser.

A very rough integer version using basin hopping:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

def f(a,b,c):
  return int(a)*np.sqrt(int(np.abs(b)))/int(c)

def loss(x, value=0.23094010767585033):
  return (f(*x)-value)**2

r=basinhopping(loss, stepsize=1, niter=10000, x0=(1,1,1), )
print(r)
print(list(map(int, r['x'])))
```

and an exemplary output

```
                        fun: 7.703719777548943e-34
 lowest_optimization_result:       fun: 7.703719777548943e-34
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([0., 0., 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 4
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 2.69160446,  3.44627592, 15.48606124])
                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
      minimization_failures: 5
                       nfev: 40004
                        nit: 10000
                       njev: 10001
                          x: array([ 2.69160446,  3.44627592, 15.48606124])
[2, 3, 15]
```

Showing that 2*sqrt(3)/15 gives your desired value up to 1e-34 error.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are infinite possibilities, here is a function which will return one of them.

```py
def lazy_solution(float_num):
    numerator = str(float_num)[2:]
    denominator = '1' + '0'*(len(numerator) - 1)
    root = 1
    return int(numerator), root, int(denominator)
```